# In C++11, can raw string literals have multiple lines?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Is this legal under C++11?

```
string s = R"(This is the first line
And this is the second line)";
```

... being equivalent to:

```
string s = "This is the first line\nAnd this is the second line";
```

Comment: [Yes !](http://ideone.com/vjxpb3) it is.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly valid. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Also, from the (draft) standard 2.14.5/4:

> A source-file new-line in a raw string literal results in a new-line
>   in the resulting execution *string-literal*. Assuming no whitespace at the beginning of lines in the
>   following example, the assert will succeed:
>
> ```
> const char *p = R"(a\
> b
> c)";
> assert(std::strcmp(p, "a\\\nb\nc") == 0);
> ```

Comment: Probably you can quote some part from standard or the reference too

Comment: Very cool - I think that C++11's raw string literals will be very handy!

Comment: @Bakuriu - It was a copy/paste error on my part. I somehow dropped the trailing \ on the first line and \\\n from the assertion.